# Circular data dependency destructor

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, graph

I am now designing my own graph class with adjacency list. I finished most of steps except for the destructor.

This is my Vertex class:

```
struct Vertex{
public:
    Vertex(){m_name="";}
    Vertex(string name):m_name(name){}
    ~Vertex(){
        cout << "vertex des" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < m_edge.size(); i++){
            delete m_edge[i];
            m_edge[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }
    string m_name;
    vector<Edge*> m_edge;
};
```

This is my Edge class:

```
struct Edge{
public:
    Edge() : m_head(nullptr), m_tail(nullptr) {m_name="";}
    Edge(string name) : m_name(name), m_head(nullptr), m_tail(nullptr) {}

    ~Edge(){
        cout << "Edge des" << endl;

        delete m_head;
        m_head = nullptr;
        delete m_tail;
        m_tail = nullptr;
    }

   string m_name;

   Vertex* m_head;
   Vertex* m_tail;
};
```

However, I noticed when destructor is called, both 2 classes actually call each other's destructor so this gives me an infinite loop. Is this design problematic? If not, is there is any way to fix this destructor issue? Thanks!

Comment: which one is the "owner" and which one is "owned"? The owner does the deleting.

Comment: Where is the `new()` that corresponds to the `delete`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I noticed when destructor is called, both 2 classes actually call each other's destructor so this gives me an infinite loop. Is this design problematic?

Your current design is problematic indeed. Dynamically allocated should only be deleted by their respective *owners*. Typically, the owner is whoever created the object and typically, there is exactly one owner. If there are more than one object, then the ownership is *shared*. Shared ownership requires a mechanism - such as reference counting - to track the current number of owners.

Judging by the destuctors, your vertices appear to be "owned" by multiple edges and the edges appear to be owned by multiple vertices. If that wasn't the case, then your graphs would be quite boring. But you haven't implemented any form of ownership tracking.

I recommend using a simpler design where edges don't own vertices nor do vertices own edges. Both of them should be owned by a parent object perhaps called `Graph`.

Comment: Yes, graph owns vertices and edges, and edges are just the references to their two vertices. If there is no compelling reason to use dynamic allocation (such as dynamic inheritance for the vertex class), then the easiest is to remove it. If it really is necessary, and since the question is tagged C++11, ownership should be made explicit using smart pointers.

Comment: I agree with @dureuill: a graph holding shared_ptr's to edges and vertices and them holding weak_ptr's to each other at least makes the destruction automatic and checkable (no dangling pointers, checkable as in you should still check the lock succeeds before using it)

Comment: @user2079303: no it doesn't, since edges and vertices hold weak_ptr's.  The graph releases them sequentially.I think you're confusing with another answer.

Comment: @stefaanv oh sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to your description. Indeed using weak pointers in vertices and edges have no such problem that I mentioned. Still (if polymorphic nodes are needeed) I wouldn't rule out using `unique_ptr`s in graph and plain pointers in nodes/edges when performance is of concern which often is - though not always - the case with graphs. I agree with dureuill completely.

Comment: Thanks! Would change my structure!

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is tagged C++11, you should first use managed pointers. Among managed pointers, [weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) can help you break the circular dependency:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Edge;

struct Vertex{
public:
    Vertex(){m_name="";}
    Vertex(string name):m_name(name){}
    ~Vertex(){
        cout << "vertex des" << endl;
        for(auto e : m_edge)
        {
            if(e->m_head.lock().get() == this)
            {
                e->m_head = nullptr;
            }
            if(e->m_tail.lock().get() == this)
            {
                e->m_tail = nullptr;
            }
        }
    string m_name;
    vector<shared_ptr<Edge>> m_edge;
};
```

Here your raw pointers were changed for `shared_ptr`s: no need to call delete on destruction, but you should tell the edges to forget the vertex (see head and tail declaration below).

```
struct Edge{
public:
    Edge(){m_name="";}
    Edge(string name):m_name(name){}

    ~Edge(){
        cout << "Edge des" << endl;
        // if you're here, this means no vertices points to the edge any more:
        // no need to inform head or tail the edge is destroyed
    }

    void do_something_to_head()
    {
        auto head = m_head.lock();
        if(head)
        {
            head->do_something();
        }
    }

   string m_name;

   weak_ptr<Vertex> m_head;
   weak_ptr<Vertex> m_tail;
};
```

The raw pointers in the edges are changed for `weak_ptr`: they are "non-owning" objects pointing to a shared resource. You can't dereference a `weak_ptr` directly: you must call the method `lock` which create a temporary `shared_ptr` to the pointed resource if its exists (thus preventing circular dependency). Usage:

```
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Vertex> v1 = make_shared<Vertex>();
    shared_ptr<Vertex> v2 = make_shared<Vertex>();

    // connection should be encapsulated somewhere

    shared_ptr<Edge> e = make_shared<Edge>();

    v1->m_edge.push_back(e);
    e->m_head = v1;

    v2->m_edge.push_back(e);
    e->m_tail = v2;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is a design issue, because, in graph terms - when you deleting the Edge - you are not supposed to delete its Vertices.

I suppose,

```
m_head = nullptr;
m_tail = nullptr;
```

is enough in your example.

Comment: It's not necessary at all then (in the destructor)?

Comment: Have a look at its constructor: (i think some part of code is skipped there) but Edge does not **construct** its Vertices, it just referncing at them. So my solution is just to null the references (for clarity).
In other class, which holds pointers and not deleting them - this will be memore leak

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to tell me? I see no need to set these pointers to `nullptr` in the destructor. And certainly they shouldn't be deleted there (I presumed this).

Comment: Yes, i didn't get you from the first comment. I thought you are telling about delete.
And - yes - this is not neccessary, because pointers are gone. Still, i would leave something like this code in the destructor, just for clarity that m_head and m_tail does not have this edge anymore. Probably, design can be changed in future so this will be self-commented code with small overhead

Comment: @grindaah That should be abundantly clear from the fact that the object is about to disappear entirely. That's a bit like insisting on writing "please ignore" on each page of a book that you are about to throw into a volcano.

Comment: You are right, i just mentioned, that **i** would keep this part, for myself.
Probably, i should edit my response to be more clear about it

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question, like others answered already, is: yes, calling eachover's destructor is problematic because this will likely result in **undefined behavior**.

For example, look at this situation:

- A `Vertex` object `v` is being deleted,
- which results in deletion of the 1st `Edge` in member vector `m_edge`,
- which results in deletion of both `m_head` and `m_tail` `Vertex`,
- assuming one of these is `v`, then the next loop in `v`'s destructor will try to access data that has been deleted !!!

At best, your program will segfault; at worst... who knows...

Your design is not that bad. Its problem, however, is that you cannot clearly define an ownership (which could help to know who should destroy who).

Indeed, assuming a `Vertex` can be in relation with several (and at least one) `Edge` and that an `Edge` is in relation with exactly two `Vertex`, then you can consider that an `Edge` is owned by a pair of `Vertex`. Not that easy to manage deletion order in that situation...

However, you don't absolutely need an ownership relation to state who should destroy who. As assumed above, an `Edge` is in relation with exactly two `Vertex`; if one of them is destroyed, then the `Edge` should be destroyed too. On the other hand, if an `Edge` is destroyed, there is no reason to destroy any of the `Vertex` in relation with it because each can still be in relation with other existing `Edge`; the single exception to this is when the `Vertex` has no more relation with any `Edge`. The code following these rules is the following:

```
struct Edge;

struct Vertex {
public:
    // ctors unchanged
    ~Vertex();  // implemented below
    void remove_relation(Edge* edge)    // for use by Edge only
    {
        std::vector<Edge*>::iterator it =
            std::find(m_edge.begin(), m_edge.end(), edge);
        if (it != m_edge.end())
             m_edge.erase(it);
        if (m_edge.size() == 0)
            delete this;  // this Vertex can be safely deleted
    }
    string        m_name;
    vector<Edge*> m_edge;
};

struct Edge {
public:
    // ctors unchanged
    ~Edge() {
        // Only have to remove relation with m_head & m_tail
        if (m_head)
            m_head->remove_relation(this);
        if (m_tail)
            m_tail->remove_relation(this);
        std::cout << "deleted Edge " << this << std::endl;
    }
    void delete_from_vertex(Vertex* from)  // for use by Vertex only
    {
        // Prevent from removing relation with the calling Vertex
        if (m_head == from)
            m_head = nullptr;
        else if (m_tail == from)
            m_tail = nullptr;
        else
            assert(false); // Vertex not in relation with this Edge
        delete this;       // finally destroy this Edge
    }
   string  m_name;
   Vertex* m_head;
   Vertex* m_tail;
};

Vertex::~Vertex() {
    for(int i = 0; i < m_edge.size(); i++)
        m_edge[i]->delete_from_vertex(this);    // special destruction
    std::cout << "deleted Vertex " << this << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/WBdXEU)